# I Cannot endure anymore. Gazebo Team, could you please carefully release your project

Tags: installation

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

With due all my respects, If a powerful software is causing countless problems which are resulted by careless posting and maintenance, it will be a totally useless one and this is gazebo.

Could you please kindly have a look at your tutorials and release instruction on your website? Almost none of them works!

*waiting for namespaces.....* when executing

*Unable to locate package gazeboXX....* when installing

Come on, what is the point to release your project and instructions when the users cannot get them?

Thank you for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12979/i-cannot-endure-anymore.-gazebo-team,-could-you-please-carefully-release-your-project./) by [puav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2534/puav/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-31

Post score: -5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2016-04-01**:
-1. People here are happy to answer specific questions you have -- general complaints are really not constructive. If you have a question on how to do a particular thing: ask. If you have a feature request, make it. If you have a bug report, file it: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues?status=new&status=open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sorry to hear that you had a bad experience. Hopefully we'll be able to assist you.

I'll need a bit more information though. Could you update your post with answers to these questions?

1. What version of Gazebo are you using?
2. What operating system are you using (such as Ubuntu Trusty, or OSX)?
3. What tutorial(s) did you try to follow?
4. What command did you execute that resulted in "waiting for namespaces....."?
5. What command did you execute that resulted in "Unable to locate package gazeboXX...."?

Every release we run through our tutorials to make sure they work. Sounds like we missed something, and we'll try to correct this situation as fast as possible.

Thanks for letting us know about your problem.

** Update **

So far you have said that you followed the tutorial exactly, and still can't install gazebo7. If this is the case, then something strange is going on. Can you please post the output to the following commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
```

.

```
 wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

. just post the last couple lines of the next one

```
sudo apt-get update
```

.

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo7
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-04-04**:
The author of this question had Ubuntu 12.04, not 14.04 as originally reported. Therefore they could not install gazebo7 as indicated here (http://gazebosim.org/#status).